# When is $L^2(\mu)$ separable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space.

> Under which further assumption are we able to show that $L^2(\mu)$ is separable?

Most lecture books on measure theory only show separability of $L^2(\mu)$ for $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)=\left(\mathbb R^d,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^{\otimes d},\lambda^{\otimes d}\right)$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

I guess (but I'm not sure) that we need something like separability of $\mathcal E$ equipped with the metric $$d_\mu(A,B):=\mu(A\Delta B)\;\;\;\text{for }A,B\in\mathcal E,$$ where $\Delta$ denotes the symmetric difference.

*Remark*: I know there are several questions regarding the separability of $L^p$-spaces on the board, but almost all of them are concered with $E=\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: The following question should be very helpful to you: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42310/when-is-l2x-separable

Comment: Practically speaking, the answer is "$(E, \mathcal{E})$ should be standard Borel".  That is not completely true because of the possibility of atoms consisting of more than one point, or additional null sets, but it should cover pretty much all real-life examples.

Comment: @NateEldredge Do you've got a reference at hand?

Comment: @PhoemueX Unfortunately, I'm struggling to follow the accepted answer. The author is claiming that "$L^2(X)$ only depends on the measurable space"; I don't get how I need to understand this claim. Actually, the notation $L^2(X)$ doesn't make even sense when there is no reference measure on $X$ ... So, how do we need to understand this?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: When the author writes "the measurable space", what he means is the tuple $(X,\mathcal{A},\mathcal{N})$, where $\mathcal{A}$ are the measurable sets, and $\mathcal{N}$ are the null sets. What he claims is that (up to isomorphism), the $L^2$ space does not actually depend on the measure, but only on this tuple $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{N})$. See also here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical-p/20820#20820. Also, you might like this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/42314/59219